# How to solve compatibility with old pandas and tensorflow on M1 chip

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, apple-m1

I am working with a MacBook Pro M1.

I have to run a code that was written several years ago and relies on python 3.6, pandas 0.20.3 and numpy 1.17.3.

On top of these packages, I should also use TensorFlow. Here's the problem. Since I am running the code on a Mac M1, I need to use `tensorflow-macos`, which is not compatible with python 3.6. Is there any other way to install a version of tensorflow compatible with python 3.6 pandas 0.20.3 and numpy 1.17.3 on an M1?

Rewriting the code will be eventually done, but right I have a timing constraint and I cannot rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the terminal and installing Python in Rosetta as described in these articles.

- https://alexslobodnik.medium.com/apple-m1-python-pandas-and-homebrew-20f14828ccc7
- https://medium.com/thinknum/how-to-install-python-under-rosetta-2-f98c0865e012
- https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-manage-multiple-python-versions-on-an-apple-silicon-m1-mac-d69ee6ed0250